# Permanently add PowerShell module? (Import-Module)

Tags: windows, powershell, module, powershell-3.0, import-module

I'm using a third-party module I found on GitHub and importing it with:

```
powershell Import-Module .\foo.ps1
```

This imports successfully and the module works great. But when I open a new PowerShell terminal, it doesn't load the module, I have to run the `Import-Module` command everytime. Is it possible to have modules load permanently?

I'm using Windows 10 with PowerShell v3.

Comment: If you install the module correctly with [Install-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-5.1) it will be loaded automatically if needed

Comment: Wow, that was super condescending and not at all helpful in any way.

Comment: Since Powershell v3 Modules will be loaded automaticall if you install them to the right place with Install-Module.

Comment: Alternatively you could place a `Import-Module .\foo.ps1` to your profile to make sure it's always loaded when you start a console.

Comment: @Olaf the part about installing so that it resides in an auto-load location is helpful, would you post it as an answer?

Comment: @vskbdvds The comment is not condescending and is in fact helpful.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, Olaf quickly modified his comment after I said that.

Comment: @vskbdvds in that case, you can delete your comment to reduce confusion.

Comment: Just to make that completely clear - I only added "with Install-Module" including the link to my first comment!!

Comment: Did you find an alternative solution? I'm having to use Import-Module in my profile for it to work.

Answer (score 8):

You can add it to one of your profiles that powershell loads by default.   Best bet is

```
%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

or

`%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb613488(v=vs.85) for the full list

Answer (score 5):

Since Powershell v3 Modules will be loaded automatically if you install them to the right place with [Install-Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-5.1).

Here are additional information about installing Powershell modules: [Installing a PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: what do you mean by the "right place"? why doesn't load automatically if I install with `Install-Module -Name MyModuleToInstall`. It only works for me if I use Import-Module before using the module commands.

Comment: The module should be installed to a path listed in `$env:PSModulePath` to get loaded automatically. You can read more about here: [Get-Help about_PSModulePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7.2)